# Cannot get spyOn test to work properly- Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, testing, karma-runner

I cannot get my test to work for some reason and it keeps throwing the error:

> Expected spy on isCurrentStatus to equal true.

The function being called simply assessed whether the passed in variable equals the currently held `status` property, and returns either true of false. Nothing major...

**Test**

```
it('should return true if current status = status passed in', () => {
    const statusSpy = spyOn(component, 'isCurrentStatus');
    component.event = failedEvent;
    component.isCurrentStatus('failed');
    expect(statusSpy).toEqual(true);
  })
```

**component**

```
event: MyEvent;

isCurrentStatus(status: string): boolean {
    return this.event.status === status;
  }
```

**UPDATE**

I just moved the `spyOn` into the `beforeEach()` section and now returns:

> expected `undefined` to equal `true`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could create a spyOn on the function and check value it returns differently:

```
spyOn(component, 'isCurrentStatus').and.callThrough();
component.event = failedEvent;
const statusResult = component.isCurrentStatus('failed');
expect(statusResult).toBeTruthy();
```

Answer (score 1):

`Expected spy on isCurrentStatus to equal true.` It because `spyOn` creates, actually, a `spy`. And you try smth like `expect(Spy).toEqual(Boolean);` so you get such error.

`expected undefined to equal true` - you get because `beforeEach()`'s scope is not in your test function (`it()`) scope

As you want to test returned value - you don't need to spy here. Just call function and check its result.

Spy is needed when you need test not return value but something else - for example, it is function of injected dependency but you need to be confident that it was called. So, you create a spy. Or: you need to check how many times was function called, what params were passed etc. Or when you need to mock its behavior.

Answer (score 0):

try this to test the returned value

```
expect(component.isCurrentStatus('failed')).toEqual(true);
```

and you can check if the method was called or not

```
const statusSpy = spyOn(component, 'isCurrentStatus').and.callThrough();
...
expect(statusSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
```

you can check arguments

```
expect(statusSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('failed')
```